# Beaglebone Black Latest Firmware Images U-Boot SPL 2018.01 not boot

Tags: beagleboneblack

I'm trying to flash Beaglebone back from element14 by step on Getting Started page , it can't flash or boot on sdcard on deabian 9.1 LXQT or 9.3 loT lasteset Firmware Image, but I can flash on Old Firmware debian7.5 from step 
"dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/mmcblk1" on  [stackoverflow this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725206/unable-to-flash-emmc-from-sd-card-beaglebone-black).
I use debug port, It show

```
U-Boot SPL 2018.01-00002-ge9ff418fb8 (Feb 20 2018 - 20:14:57)
Trying to boot from MMC1

U-Boot 2018.01-00002-ge9ff418fb8 (Feb 20 2018 - 20:14:57 -0600), Build: jenkins-github_Bootloader-Builder-38

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
Reset Source: Power-on reset has occurred.
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Using default environment
```

what should I do?
thanks you.

Comment: Wrong place for this. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Not OS installation or firmware installation questions. Perhaps ask on SuperUser?

Comment: sorry very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following procedure with your required images from https://beagleboard.org/latest-images

http://old.ghielectronics.com/community/forum/topic?id=23763