# Flashing beagle bone for use with Codesys

Tags: flashing, beagle

I am looking to use a beagle bone black with codesys to read signals through the CANBUS.

I am following the instructions from codesys on how to install their software on the beaglebone. The first thing is to flash the BBB with the latest debian image. For this I am using Balena etcher, which says it has completed successfully. It has taken about 4GB on the SD card and I cannot view the files as they are in a partition, is this correct?

Following the usual intrustions like :[https://beagleboard.org/getting-started#:~:text=The%20access%20point%20password%20defaults,8](https://beagleboard.org/getting-started#:%7E:text=The%20access%20point%20password%20defaults,8). doesn't make the 4 LED's light up in the pattern like I've seen on videos. And therefore the image hasn't flashed?

I started to follow the instructions : [Unable to Flash eMMC from SD Card BeagleBone Black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725206/unable-to-flash-emmc-from-sd-card-beaglebone-black) however when I use the line "sudo nano boot/uEnv.txt" I get the error "Directory 'boot' does not exist".

[image]

Does this mean there is an issue with the image? However, I have used more than one SD card and re flashed them etc.

Any help would be great!